# libspotify API: when does password blob expire?

Tags: spotify

As per API document, **credentials_blob_updated** callback is called when storable credentials have been updated. But in "spshell" example, blob for storage is kept refreshing from time to time even if there is no credential change. Is it normal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. A blob is valid until a new blob is created, the user changes their password, or the TTL of the blob itself is reached (this is a really long time, I believe multiple years).

Whenever you get the `credentials_blob_updated` callback, just replace your existing blob for that user with the new one and you'll be fine.